# Longest domino chain/sequence

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to find the longest chain of dominoes possible, given a set of 12 randomly picked dominoes. I've already recursively generated all possibilities of dominoes (there are 91 possibilities using face values of 0 to 12). A domino consists of one "brick" with two squares on it: [a|b] where 0 =< a, b <= 12. Thus, an example of a domino could be [12, 0] or [6, 3] etc. Dominoes may be connect if adjacent halves have the same value.

Dominoes may be flipped to accommodate a match. For example, given [8, 4], [9, 4] could be flipped to make the pair [8, 4][4, 9]

The following (relevant to this question) methods are available for this class:

```
void flipEnds(); // Flips the domino
int getLeft() const;
int getRight() const;
bool hasBeenPlayed() const;
void setPlayed(bool value);
```

So, sample data for this problem would be as follows:

```
 myDomino #0: [1 12 ]
    myDomino #1: [0  5 ]
    myDomino #2: [7  9 ]
    myDomino #3: [2  7 ]
    myDomino #4: [7 12 ]
    myDomino #5: [4  8 ]
    myDomino #6: [8 10 ]
    myDomino #7: [3 11 ]
    myDomino #8: [11 12 ]
    myDomino #9: [10 11 ]
    myDomino #10: [2  9 ]
    myDomino #11: [2  4 ]
```

This is more of a math problem, but how can I find the longest chain of dominoes? I assume it must be done recursively.

Comment: Please share some code you have already written that doesn't work and maybe we can point out your mistakes.  Even pseudo-code is a good start.  You won't find much support here to write the first draft of your code for you.

Comment: My apologies, I must not have been clear. I've written all of the code to setup the dominoes (finding all 91 possible distinct dominoes, and dealing 12 random ones). My question should have been phrased, "Might I ask for some suggestions as to how to start this method of finding the longest sequence?" I certainly wasn't looking for someone to do my work :) Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sequence of dominos might be represented as {#3,Y}, {#4,N}, {#0,Y}, ... The first number is the number of the domino in your hand and the second is whether it is flipped or not. We want to check every possible sequence, but prune obviously illegal one early.

Lets assume you have a function `testSequence(sequence)` which tests is a sequence is valid. 
Keep two lists, one of the current sequence `currentSeq`, and one of the dominos you have not yet chosen `unused`.

A recursion might be like

```
checkAllSeq( currentSeq, unused ) {

   foreach( domino in unused ) {
      unused2 = unused - domino   // remove domino from unused list
      seq1 = currentSeq + {domino,true}   // add unfliped domino to sequence to test
      if( testSequence(seq1) ) {
          checkAllSeq(seq1,unused2)       // recurse
      }
      // now do it with the domino flipped
      seq2 = currentSeq + {domino,false}
      if( testSequence(seq2) ) {
          checkAllSeq(seq2,unused2)
      }
   }
}
```

I've missed a few things out. This just tests all possible sequences it does not do anything with the result.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just needed some starting points. This worked! :)

Comment: @user3083948 it would be awesome if you can provide whole code sniplet

Comment: Thx for writing this

Answer (score 2):

I think you could phrase this problem as a tree-traversal pretty easily, to get a brute-force solution.

The "root" of the tree is your first choice of domino. The children of that node will be each domino that could be added to it. Each level down is adding one to the length of the chain of dominoes.

Also, remember that each added domino can be added to either the "head" or "tail" of the chain — that will increase the number of possible children for a given node.

Many of the chains will be cut short because you run out of choices — put another way, many nodes in the tree will have no children. This will speed up your search.

Once phrased this way, your problem is to do a tree traversal to find the longest chain in that tree. Sounds like a good application for recursion (:

Answer (score 1):

Note that it's always possible to get an iterative solution to any problem that can be solved recursively, and vice versa. But I agree that recursive is easier for this problem (it usually is).

For any recursive problem, you have to deal with three cases: the initial case, the middle cases, and the terminal case. Here, the initial case is when you have no dominos played (so you can play any domino, in either orientation); the middle case is when you are required to play a domino that matches the most recent one; the terminal case is when there is no domino that can be added to the last one, or when all dominos have been played.

You need to keep track of two lists of dominos: one for the current best-known match, and one for the current match attempt.

If you managed to play all the dominos, return early; otherwise the best possible input will actually take the longest.

This is the naive approach, which is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) (the possibility of a both ends of the domino having the same number does not significantly affect the problem; it just adds 0.5 to the weight of each edge); it is likely to be worth using heuristics.

Regardless, I strongly suggest sorting your dominos first and erroring out if there are duplicates (remember to canonicalize flips), since duplicates would require a somewhat different approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this too, so I coded it. Here's my solution, based loosely on the pseudocode by salix alba above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Tile 
{
    int val[2];
};

Tile *tiles = NULL;
int nbtiles = 0;

struct Sequence 
{
    int flip;
    int used;
};
Sequence *seq = NULL;    
int *order = NULL;
int maxlevel = 0;

int usage (char *name)
{
    cerr << "usage: " << name << " start_value tile_left tile_right {tile_left tile_right} ... " << endl;
    return 1;
}

int readTiles (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ((argc & 0x1) != 0) 
        return (usage (argv[0]));
    if (argc < 4)
        return (usage (argv[0]));
    nbtiles = (argc - 2) / 2;
    tiles = new Tile[nbtiles];
    int side = 0;
    int itile = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    {
        tiles[itile].val[side] = atoi (argv[i]);
        side = 1 - side;
        if (side == 0)
        {
            itile++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int findLongest (int start, int level)
{
    int ret = 0;

    //The "if" below inefficient, but don't care, done at most nbtiles times
    if (level > maxlevel) 
    {
        cout << "new high level " << level;
        for (int lev = 0; lev < level; lev++)
        {
            int used = seq[lev].used;
            if (used) order[used] = lev;
        }
        for (int ind = 1; ind < level; ind++)
        {
            int lev = order[ind];
            int flip = seq[lev].flip;
            cout << " (" << tiles[lev].val[flip] << "," << tiles[lev].val[1 - flip] << ")";
        }
        cout << endl;
        maxlevel = level;
    }
    
    for (int itile = 0; itile < nbtiles; itile++)
    {
        if (seq[itile].used == 0)
        {
            for (int flip = 0; flip < 2; flip++)
            {
                if (tiles[itile].val[flip] == start)
                {
                    seq[itile].flip = flip;
                    seq[itile].used = level;
                    findLongest (tiles[itile].val[ 1 - flip], level + 1);
                    seq[itile].used = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = readTiles (argc, argv);
    if (ret != 0) return ret;
    
    //for (int i = 0; i < nbtiles; i++)
        //cout << tiles[i].val[0] << " " << tiles[i].val[1] << endl;

    int start = atoi (argv[1]);
    seq = new Sequence[nbtiles];
    order = new int[nbtiles];

    findLongest (start, 1);
    return 0;
}
```