# How to calculate domino-chain for integer pairs?

Tags: java, algorithm

The problem I'm facing is more like of algorithmic nature.

Let's say that I have a list of pair objects containing integers. Is there a way to sort the list so that the second part of the pair is equal to first part of the next pair?

For instance given this list of pairs:
 A = Pair(2,1),Pair(2,3),Pair(1,3).

After sorting the list becomes:
A = Pair(1,3), Pair(3,2),Pair(2,1).

As you can see it is allowed to change the order of values inside the pair like the Pair(2,3) which became Pair(3,2).

I though about using comparator or comparable interfaces but they dont cover complex cases like the above.

Comment: Well, that result is pretty random, isn't it? Why is your solution correct, but not "(1,2) - (2,3) - (3,1)"? Or are both solutions correct and acceptable?

Comment: My first question is: what behavior when the sort is not possible like with [(1,2),(3,4)]? Is the sort always possible in your case? I think comparator and comparable won't help you in that case, you will have to write your own algorithm to do that. In particular, Comparator and Comparable can't switch Pair and they act locally (two objects by the time), here you need to act globally. For example, in this case: [(1,2)(2,1)(2,3)] the two first elements seems to be ok, but if we switch them, it allows to place the third.

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to finding a Eulerian path in a graph: https://www.google.com/search?q=find+eulerian+path

Comment: @Tom Both solutions are acceptable.

Comment: @aman I am not sure I get what you say. How do you define maximum pairs?

Comment: so you want to play  [domino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominoes) (including the turning of tiles)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Longest domino chain/sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189818/longest-domino-chain-sequence)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206913

Comment: Thanks @tkruse. That is exactly what I'm looking for.